# Set background in body or html

Tags: html, css, background

Is there a difference between setting background in css with body or html? Both work.

eg:

```
body{
    background: green;
}
```

or

```
html{
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is a very interesting article.**

https://css-tricks.com/html-vs-body-in-css/

Answer (score 1):

The `<html>` background is "behind" the `<body>` background. Try this to see what I mean:

```
html{
  background-color:blue;
}
body{
  background-color:white;
  max-width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```